# Set Values when user is created on Firebase - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase

I am trying to create a user in Firebase and save the user information at the time the user gets created. This is my action function where I create the user:

```
@IBAction func createAccountButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {

            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                } else {
                    let userID =  (user?.uid)! as String
                    self.bringerUser.userRef = userID as String
                    let userEmail:String = self.emailTextField.text!
                    print(userEmail)
                    print(self.bringerUser.userRef! as String)
                    self.ref.child("users").child(self.bringerUser.userRef! as String).child("userInfo").setValue(["email": emailTextfield.text])
                }
            })
    }
```

The user ID is nil when trying to access and write data on Firebase  but if I print it it works fine. The error I get is this:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).child("userInfo").setValue(["email": emailTextfield.text])
```

Comment: I get an error : Value of type 'FIRAuth?' has no member 'auth' and also: 'init()' is unavailable.

Comment: Getting this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. The userID prints the user ID with no errors.

Comment: Ok. I think you are right. I cant test it since I am getting this error: We have blocked all requests from this device due to unusual activity. Try again later.   I dont know what it means but it seems Firebase is not letting me create accounts.