# Firebase login with phone number deletes the signup/Signin details of the logged in user

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

Making an app in swift 4 and made phone number login authentication with firebase .

but the issue is when i log into the app after entering the otp recieved the real time data base shows no data of the logged in user .

Answer (score 1):

If you're set up with Firebase, check the Authentication tab on the left and you should see all users there (if they've been successfully created). You'll have access to their email and uid from that tab, but if you want to store more user data in a realtime database, you'll need to do that yourself. Links above are super helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication does not automatically store data for its users in the Firebase Realtime Database, or in Cloud Firestore. If you need user information in the database, you will have to store it there yourself.

Here are some questions that show how to do this:

- [Swift & Firebase - How to store more user data other than email and password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37927186/swift-firebase-how-to-store-more-user-data-other-than-email-and-password)
- [How do I link each user to their data in Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30910704/how-do-i-link-each-user-to-their-data-in-firebase)
- [Add Extra Details on Firebase User Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038611/add-extra-details-on-firebase-user-table)
- [Set Values when user is created on Firebase - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390495/set-values-when-user-is-created-on-firebase-swift)